# Report mistakes in Java SE documentation

Tags: java, oracle, documentation

Is there any place to go to report documentation mistakes and typos to Oracle?

For example, the documentation for [Scanner#findWithinHorizon(String pattern, int horizon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) states that

> An invocation of this method of the form findWithinHorizon(pattern)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>   findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile(pattern, horizon)).

What is means to say is

> ...as the invocation findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile(pattern),
>   horizon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `submit a bug/feature` at the bottom. Clicking it leads [here](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/). I'm guessing the desired category is:

> Java Platform Standard Edition

and the subcategory,

> JDK/JRE Documentation, API, tutorials (doc)

Answer (score 1):

From the bottom of the page you linked: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/